# Why we have boolean type?

Tags: c, boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-operations

I learned that C does not have the boolean type. When I read "Ocaml from very beginning", I encountered a question in page12 :

Why we cannot just use 0 and 1 to represent the boolean type in camel, like the way C language does?

Comment: why does BASIC use line numbers while C doesn't? why does pascal use `begin`/`end` instead of `{`/`}`? That's how they were designed/specified...

Comment: Can you help me to answer the question in my book : Why ocaml needs boolean type?

Comment: sorry @overloading but it is a ridiculous question. Maybe you want to know why we need types at all, since all is cast down to bit patterns. Should be obvious why we do.

Comment: no idea. but you rarely "NEED" something in a language. after all, they all compile down to some kind of machine code in the end, and there's no real "boolean" at that level at all.

Comment: What makes you think C doesn't have a boolean type? [It indeed has](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/boolean). Sure it's not on the same level as e.g. `int` or `char`, but it does have it.

Comment: The one that I learned is C90  and it does not have boolean type, but you can #define true 1  #define false 0 @JoachimPileborg

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Actually `_Bool` is at the same level. It is an integer type.

Comment: @overloading: C99 is now >16 years old. And C11 5 years. Time to learn something new. There are quite some other interesting features! Note that without a specific tag, we have to assume standard C, which is C11. There is no other **valid** C standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why some languages have boolean type but others don't?

Because some languages have a better [type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system) than others. In my opinion, for many (but not all) tasks, Ocaml has a better type system than C.

<sup>(but your question is too broad & matter of opinion)</sup>

The C type system was closely inspired by the hardware ([PDP-11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-11)) and [instruction set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set) available at the time (early 1970s) C was designed.

Comment: C - providing all the power of assembler, with all the legibility of assembler.